# how can I insert a variable in a line of code?

Tags: python

I want to let the user to choose which file to open using a string variable. Basically I want to learn how can I tell Python to use a variable in a code section.

I have the following code:

```
def call_file(fn1):
    import fn1

filename = input("Name of the file to import")
call_file(filename)
```

And inside the same folder i have the helloWorld.py with:

```
print("hello world")
```

Comment: What do you mean by *tell Python to use a variable in a code section*?

Comment: Your question is not clear. I think you are already letting users choose the file they want to by using input.

Comment: This would appear to successfully import a file based on user I/O as long as the file existed. What's the question?

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar exactly, that was my question. I would really appreciate it if you help me. :)

Comment: What do you wish to achieve with this code? The code looks fine as it already does what it has to do and I don't see any errors.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter & Vin: Actually it gives me an error:
 File mporterbyinput.py", line 5, in <module>
    call_file(filename)
  File Importerbyinput.py", line 2, in call_file
    import fn1
ImportError: No module named 'fn1

Comment: But that's arbitrary since you don't already have a module names fn1 try replacing fn1 with a module you actually have.

Comment: Are you working in Ubuntu or some other Linux flavor ?

Comment: @Vin Ehm.. I do not understand a lot about programming, can you give me a more simple example please?

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar Windows

Comment: Fortunately for you, John1024 figured out your problem; your question should be much clearer, though. First, *always* include your error message (if you have one) in your question; you should *not* be putting it in the comments in response to requests for clarification. Second, in this case, your question doesn't make any sense; your real problem is how the import statement works, not how variable scoping works. You should be asking something like "why doesn't this import statement using a variable work".

Comment: Go ahead and use John1024's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have found, the `import` statement does not accomplish what you need. Try this instead:

```
from importlib import import_module

def call_file(fn1):
    return import_module(fn1)

filename = input("Name of the file to import: ")
usermodule = call_file(filename)
```

The `import_module` function allows you to import a module given as an argument.  The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) have more information on this function.

#### Example

Running under `ipython`, we can use the code above to import the `os` module and access it under the name `usermodule`:

```
In [3]: run t.py
Name of the file to import: os
In [4]: usermodule.stat('t.py')
Out[4]: os.stat_result(st_mode=33200, st_ino=97969455, st_dev=2066, st_nlink=1, st_uid=5501, st_gid=5501, st_size=196, st_atime=1462081283, st_mtime=1462081283, st_ctime=1462081283)
```

#### Improvement

If the file the user asks for cannot be imported, the code should handle the error, possibly like this:

```
try:
    usermodule = call_file(filename)
except ImportError:
    print('Sorry, that file could not be imported.')
```

#### Alternative

It is also possible to import modules from a variable name using `__import__`:

```
>>> mod = 'math'
>>> new = __import__(mod)
>>> new.cos(0)
1.0
```

Note, however, that the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) frowns on this:

> Direct use of `__import__()` is also discouraged in favor of
>   `importlib.import_module()`.

Comment: Should this not be inside a `try`, in case the user types in name that doesn't exist?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ OK.  I added an example of error handling.

Comment: The only issue I see with this method is that the module will only exist within the scope of the variable and not in sys.modules[name]. You can check using    `modulenames = set(sys.modules)&set(globals())    
allmodules = [sys.modules[name] for name in modulenames]` This would only become necessary assuming the program needed to later check a list of all imported modules but based on the OP I assume he will!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the sys module to achieve the same effect as importing a module as some other name.

```
import sys

def my_import(name):
    __import__(name)
    return sys.modules[name]

module = my_import('random') #just for testing
print module.randint(0,1) #just for testing
```

Below code can be used to grab module at certain depths!

```
def my_import(name):
    m = __import__(name)
    for n in name.split(".")[1:]:
        m = getattr(m, n)
    return m

m = __import__("xml.etree.ElementTree") # returns xml
m = my_import("xml.etree.ElementTree") # returns ElementTree
```